# Assign a value for movement within the neighbourhood in NetLogo

Tags: probability, netlogo

In NetLogo I would like to modify this code:

```
to go 
    ask patches with [not any? turtles-here]
    [ move-particle-to-here ]
    tick
    end

    to move-particle-to-here 
      let particle one-of turtles-on neighbors4
      if particle != nobody [
        ask particle [ move-to myself ] 
      ]
    end
```

and assign a value or probability for volume exclusive movement within the neighbourhood.

I have two breeds, one called 'solvent' and one called 'particle'. I want to ask the particles and solvent to move only with a certain probability or value. For example if a particle has 3 solvents in its neighbors4, it will move will a probability of (probability)^3.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as I have found little by searching online.

Thanks!

Comment: That `probability ^ 3` seems odd. What exactly is `probability` the probability of?

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't explain that well enough. Say for example you have a probability of B=0.3 where B is the probability that when a 'solvent' is next to a 'particle' cell, they will move away(or be repelled) from each other with a probability B=0.3.  For the above example it would be 0.3*0.3*0.3=0.9, I want to know how to incorporate the 0.9 into the movement.

Comment: 0.3*0.3*0.3 is 0.027, not 0.9

Comment: Lol thanks too many late nights.

Comment: OK, but that still leaves the question open of whether you want to add the probabilities, or multiply them, or what. What is your intended meaning?

Comment: It's ok I have now solved my problem with about 20 lines of code, completely re-writing above.